# angularjs sortable json

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I got an Json message as follows, in the json message, if the attributes: description, title, option does not empty, there is an **position** attribute. In the position array, there is three values, the first value message the order.

I am trying to print the json message in html, according to the order (position[0]), I think the tricky thing is, the position is in different attributes.

So I cannot use

```
ng-repeat="question in questions | orderBy:'Question.description.position[0]
```

to print html in order.

Is there any other way to do that?

Here is the json message:

```
[
   {
      "Question":{
         "description":{
            "default":""
         },
         "options":[
            {
               "value":{

               }
            }
         ],
         "title":{
            "text":{
               "default":"hello world"
            },
            "position":[
               0,
               12,
               0
            ]
         }
      },
      "Selection":"text"
   },
   {
      "Question":{
         "description":{
            "default":"description hello 2",
            "position":[
               2,
               12,
               0
            ]
         },
         "options":[
            {
               "value":{

               }
            }
         ],
         "title":{
            "text":{
               "default":"hello 2"
            },
            "position":[
               1,
               12,
               0
            ]
         }
      },
      "Selection":"paragraph"
   },
   {
      "Question":{
         "description":{
            "default":"description hello 3",
            "position":[
               4,
               12,
               0
            ]
         },
         "options":[
            {
               "value":{
                  "default":"1"
               },
               "position":[
                  5,
                  12,
                  0
               ]
            },
            {
               "value":{
                  "default":"2"
               },
               "position":[
                  6,
                  12,
                  0
               ]
            }
         ],
         "title":{
            "text":{
               "default":"hello 3"
            },
            "position":[
               3,
               12,
               0
            ]
         }
      },
      "Selection":"radio"
   },
   {
      "Question":{
         "description":{
            "default":"description hello 4",
            "position":[
               8,
               12,
               0
            ]
         },
         "options":[
            {
               "value":{
                  "default":"check11"
               },
               "position":[
                  9,
                  12,
                  0
               ]
            },
            {
               "value":{
                  "default":"check22"
               },
               "position":[
                  10,
                  12,
                  0
               ]
            }
         ],
         "title":{
            "text":{
               "default":"hello 4"
            },
            "position":[
               7,
               12,
               0
            ]
         }
      },
      "Selection":"checkbox"
   },
   {
      "Question":{
         "description":{
            "default":"description hello 5",
            "position":[
               12,
               12,
               0
            ]
         },
         "options":[
            {
               "value":{
                  "default":"list1"
               },
               "position":[
                  13,
                  12,
                  0
               ]
            },
            {
               "value":{
                  "default":"list2"
               },
               "position":[
                  14,
                  12,
                  0
               ]
            }
         ],
         "title":{
            "text":{
               "default":"hello 5"
            },
            "position":[
               11,
               12,
               0
            ]
         }
      },
      "Selection":"list"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a function to the `orderBy` filter in your template:

```
ng-repeat="question in questions | orderBy:getPosition"
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.getPosition = function(question) {
  // Your logic here to get the position according to which attributes are presents
  return position;
};
```

Comment: thanks! could you explain it in detail? from the beginning, I need to know which one is 0, then I can print it in html, rather than determine html first then look for attributes.